# Android 7.1 denied accessing to proc file. How can we get the running processes?

Tags: android, process, android-7.1-nougat

Android 7.1 denied accessing to proc file. How can we get the running processes ?

Comment: Root your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the shell command 'top -n 1' to get the stream, and filter it to get the running process

Comment: How can we get it in Android runtime?